# IndexError: list index out of range - python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, opencsv

I have the following error:

```
currency = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
 crntAmnt = int(input("Please enter the amount of money to convert: "))
    print(currencies)
    exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv','r')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    crntCurrency = input("Please enter the current currency: ")
    validateloop=0
    while validateloop == 0:
        for row in exchReader:
                currency = row[0]
                if currency == crntCurrency:
                    crntRt = row[1]
                    validateloop=+1
```

Heres the CSV file:

Japanese Yen,169.948

US Dollar,1.67

Pound Sterling,1

Euro,5.5

Here's an input/Output example:

```
Please enter the amount of money to convert: 100
['Pound Sterling', 'Euro', 'US Dollar', 'Japanese Yen']
Please enter the current currency: Pound Sterling
```

Comment: I have often found the humble `print` statement most efficacious... for example, you could use it to see what's in `row`.

Comment: as @kindall said, can you put a couple of print statements and show us what they output? Or you can show us what is in `exchangeRate.csv`...

Comment: i do not c how that would be useful?

Comment: ... you don't see how it would be useful to know whether `row` has a zeroth element, or is in fact a list at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a blank row in your csv file, causing it to produce an empty list

There are a couple solutions

---

1. Check if there are elements, only proceed if there are:

```
for row in exchReader:
    if len(row):  # can also just do   if row:
        currency = row[0]
        if currency == crntCurrency:
```

---

2. Short-circuit an `and` operator to make `currency` an empty list, which won't match `crntCurrency`:

```
for row in exchReader:
    currency = row and row[0]
    if currency == crntCurrency:
```

Answer (score 2):

Try printing out the row. The convention for variable names in python are `like_this` and not `likeThis`. You might find the `break` keyword useful:

```
for row in exch_reader:
    currency = row[0]
    if currency == crnt_currency:
        crnt_rt = row[1]
        break
```

To only index the row when the row actually contains something:

```
currency = row and row[0]
```

Here `row[0]` is only executed if `row` evaluates to `True`, which would be when it has at least one element.